# Is my runtime analysis of the code segment correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

This is similar to this question [runtime analysis of the following recursive method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001335/runtime-analysis-of-the-following-recursive-method)

I am trying to analyze this code segment 
[image]

To analyze this, I saw that the outer loop was going to execute n/c times. And then for every time the outer loop runs, the inner loop will also execute n/c times. Therefore in total, this segment will run n^2/c^2 or O(n^2) if you drop the constant.

Is there also a visual way you can do this as well, similar to (from http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/15wi/lectures/lecture3.pdf) slide 19 ? I tried doing this but got  (c *(n)(n + 1))/2  which I wasn't sure was right.

[image]

Comment: @I.K. Please enlighten me :), do you just multiply every term by C?

Comment: `n^2` makes the largest contribution in `(c *(n)(n + 1))/2` as `n` becomes large, so you can drop everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, here is how would analyze it now

The most times that the outer loop will run is <sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>c</sub> and for everytime an iteration of the outer loop runs, the inner loop will also run at most <sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>c</sub> times.

Therefore the worst case Big O runtime of this algorithm is *O(<sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup>⁄<sub>c<sup>2</sup></sub>)* or *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

Answer (score 0):

(c *(n)(n + 1))/2

= c*(n^2 + n)/2

= (c/2)*(n^2 + n)

dropping the constants and keeping the highest power of n gives a final answer of O(n^2)

Comment: yeah that too, just that last part isn't equal to n^2/c^2. I don't think it matters, does it ?